# Prim & Kruskal : Minimum Distance UVA Judge

Tags: java

I'm solving Prim's problem on UVA, 10034: 
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=975

But I'm having a problem. Consider the input:

```
7 //Number of points
4.0 0.0 //Xcoord Ycoord
1.0 0.0
3.0 9.0
1.0 9.0
2.0 8.0
5.0 5.0
1.0 5.0
```

UVA gives solution 17.99 (3.0 + 5.0 + 5.0990195135927845 + 4.0), but if you try to draw this graph, the solution 17.99 doesn't cover all the points. Instead, it only covers points:

```
4.0 0.0
1.0 0.0
5.0 5.0
1.0 5.0
```

How is it possible that you connect all the dots in a graph with only 4 points?

I know this isn't an easy question to explain, but if someone could help me.

EDIT:
I tested here: http://uvatoolkit.com/problemssolve.php

Comment: Where did you get that solution? When I followed the link that solution wasn't listed on the page.

Comment: You need to go here:
http://uvatoolkit.com/problemssolve.php
Search for 10034 and test the input above.

Comment: Well, to answer part of your question: it isn't possible that a minimum spanning tree could span the graph by only touching a few vertices. By definition, a spanning tree must span all the vertices of the graph.